# How can I pass OR in Auth::attempt method?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have Laravel project and I want to allow users to log in using a username or email but I haven't found any way to pass Or Condition in Auth::attempt()  method.

I used below code for logged via email only,

```
Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with condition of email validation check

Example:

```
$field = filter_var($request->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';

if (Auth::attempt([$field => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], true)) {
    // ...
}
```

You can find more about FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_email.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If the first attempt fails, do another attempt against username:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])
 || Auth::attempt(['username' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')]))
{
   // Login success..
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to be done in only one Auth::attempt()  method?